# How to get list of all compute disks of GCP for all the regions using java sdk

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am able to fetch list of disks by using gcloud command

```
gcloud compute disks list
```

But I am not able to do the same thing using java sdk.
Here is my sample code:

```
  DiskList execute = compute.disks().list("ProjectID", "us-ZoneId")
                .execute();
```

In the above code it is always expecting the zone as a input parameter.
I have used "aggregatedList" API also but no luck.

Is there anyway to fetch all the disks on the project using java sdk?

Comment: I reviewed the gcloud command and it use the aggregated list. What it doesn't work with your try?

Comment: Whenever I am using aggregatedList  API it is returning  the result like : 
  regions/us-central1: {"warning":{"code":"NO_RESULTS_ON_PAGE","data":[{"key":"scope","value":"regions/us-central1"}],"message":"There are no results for scope 'regions/us-central1' on this page."}}
But I want to return only whenever the disks are available in the region, not understanding how to apply filter on it. can you please help me on it?

Comment: When you use the aggregated list, you receive a list of zone and the disk's description in each zone. You have to iterate on the items entry of the response.

Comment: I added code sample.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but My requirement is customer will add the disk label(The disk can be any zone) then, I want to fetch only those disks and perform some operation,  to do this I believe I have to apply filter on labels but I am not understanding how to apply the filter on aggeratedAPI. I was able to do the same with disk list API but the disk list APIs works for only one zone.

Comment: I added a sample with the label filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a code sample that worked for me

```java
        DisksClient disksClient = DisksClient.create();
        DisksClient.AggregatedListPagedResponse aggregatedListPagedResponse = disksClient.aggregatedList("ProjectID");
        for (Map.Entry<String, DisksScopedList> entry : aggregatedListPagedResponse.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            for (Disk disk:entry.getValue().getDisksList()){
                System.out.println(disk);
            }
        }
```

---

**EDIT 1**

To filter on a specific label that have any value (here label `test`), you can do that

```java
        DisksClient disksClient = DisksClient.create();
        AggregatedListDisksRequest request = AggregatedListDisksRequest.newBuilder().setFilter("labels.test:*").setProject("ProjectID").build();
        DisksClient.AggregatedListPagedResponse aggregatedListPagedResponse = disksClient.aggregatedList(request);
        for (Map.Entry<String, DisksScopedList> entry : aggregatedListPagedResponse.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            for (Disk disk:entry.getValue().getDisksList()){
                System.out.println(disk);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help,  Can you please tell me how to apply filters on label name.                         I am able to apply filter based on label name on gcloud command but when I am applying the same  on java SDK it is hanging .                                                                              Example :   gcloud compute disks list --filter="labels=mylabelName"                                    but the same not working with java sdk   ".setFilter("labels=mylabelName")"